# i am not able to install firebase dependencies

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
? Do you want to install dependencies now? Yes
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\shars\onedrive\desktop\web development\test\functions\venv\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
C:\Users\shars\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\test\functions\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

PS C:\Users\shars\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\test>  python.exe -m pip install pip==23.2.1
Requirement already satisfied: pip==23.2.1 in c:\users\shars\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)
```

this is the firebase debug log

```
[info] +  Wrote functions/requirements.txt 
[info] +  Wrote functions/.gitignore 
[info] +  Wrote functions/main.py 
[debug] [2023-09-01T11:53:35.945Z] Running command with virtualenv: command="C:\Users\shars\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\test\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat", args=["","&&","pip3","install","--upgrade","pip"]
[debug] [2023-09-01T11:53:39.210Z] Error: spawn "C:\Users\shars\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\test\functions\venv\Scripts\activate.bat" ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\shars\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\shars\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\shars\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

i was working on a react project and i want to use the firebase funcitons for some api but i am not able to install the firebase dependencies.

Comment: Th `activate.bat` file does not exist. Review the path you have specified.